# TFS Git repo authentication failed via API

Tags: git, tfs

We have recently setup a new TFS hosted git repository. I am able to access the repo via GIT bash or via TFS browser.

The URL looks like: http://mytfs.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/SampleTFSGit

Now we have a java application which is basically pulls out source code from various git server using Git API. But for this particular TFS hosted git repo i am not able to pass the authentication. It gives me HTTP response code: 401 for the same URL: http://mytfs.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/api/v3/session

Does the Git api V3 not worked on TFS hosted GIT repo, or i am making any mistakes here. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

No, not supported. For Git, there is a special **source import API**. Details you can refer to the GitHub link: https://developer.github.com/changes/2016-02-19-source-import-preview-api/

Or you can also use **rest API** to achieve it:

e.g.

```
GET http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/_apis/git/repositories
```

More detail info: https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/git/overview